# Nav bar is broken in Chrome not in IE or Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, magento-1.9

The navigation bar was working fine till today. It is breaking in Chrome. But sometimes after few refreshing, it works fine. It's like 1 in 10. It's just happening. It's magento 1.9.2. Chrome version is 43.0.1

The text of the nav bar is uppercase and bold when it works.

```css
.novaworks-navigation #novaworks-nav > li.level0 > a > span {
  line-height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

But when it is not working, during element inspection, nothing such as these rules shows up. There are some user agent style-sheet is showing up. And the text is also not uppercase or not even bold.

```css
i, cite, em, var, address, dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Also the search box at right has a magnifier icon. But now it is also not showing up. The class for font-awesome shows no rules apart from font-style. It says User Agent Stylesheet.

But when it works, the rule for font-awesome search bar is:

```css
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't post some code

Comment: Also, you have an error when loading the page (Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).sticky is not a function)

Comment: @Vinc199789 Thanks. I am still figuring out why is this happening.

Comment: @RyanBeaulieu Hey, thanks I am looking into it. But is this error because of this ? How to get rid of this error. Let me see if I can get rid of this.

Comment: About that error. `.sticky` is not a jquery attribute so you must have a plugin. make sure you load the plugin properly. And it looks like you are using something like a md5 hash. Don't use this if you publish your site to the public because this is a very weak security. I use md5 to and only for testing

Comment: @Vinc199789 Thanks for pointing that out. It's SHA1 hash. will have to consider it. But how to solve this error ? Any idea. As in Fireforx it is working even with the same error message. What could be the real trouble with CSS ? Any Bugs in Chrome or something

Answer (score 0):

The trouble was due to animate.css. It might be little incompatible with the latest version of Chrome 43.0.1.

You have to put the general animation rule after the browser specific ones:

```css
-webkit-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
   -moz-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
     -o-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
        animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate; /* this comes last */
```

Thanks. I hope it helps.